# Display information on the top right in C

Tags: c, printing, screen, permanent

I'm trying to program a simple rpg game in C and I would want to **display some permanent information on the top right of the screen**.
Right now I've only seen the text and information that i print to screen at the bottom, but I was wondering whether it was possible to display constantly and update certain text on the screen.
The information that i would want to display would be:

```
struct character {
    char name[20];
    int HP;
    int MP;
    int AC;
};
```

And Update it as the game progresses.

So the output would be something like this:

```
Name: test
HP: 15
MP: 7
AC: 13

//rest of the information and dialogues
```

Is this possible in C?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This has nothing to do with C and everything to do with your terminal.

Comment: @Cheatah so this is impossible in C?

Comment: The spacing generally depends on terminal and IDE. Are you creating any widget to display the information?

Comment: Of course that's possible. But you need to know how your terminal works. If you are using Linux take a look at ncurses.

Comment: @AnkushPandit I'm fairly new to C so I have never tried widgets, but if they can be usefull i might give them a go

Comment: @koder Sadly i'm using Windows

Comment: "ncurses" is available on Windows, too. As others said, this issue is about your terminal, not your programming language.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone for the help, i'll look into ncurses

Comment: The magic keyword should be **VT100** (might not work on Windows)